# Registered WordPress Sidebar not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I have a sidebar in WordPress I've registered like so:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => '404',
    'name' => __('404', 'jointstheme'),
    'description' => __('The 404 sidebar.', 'jointstheme'),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

I duplicated my existing 'sidebar.php' file and created a file called: **sidebar-404.php**.

I also added the call to my sidebar in the 404 page template like so:

```
<?php get_sidebar('404'); ?>
```

Yet for some reason, my theme keeps defaulting to the default sidebar.

Anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed my question was downvoted. I searched StackOverflow first to try and find a solution. I also took great care to show my code. I would love to know why it was voted down since no reason was given. Was there something I could have done better in asking my questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register a sidebar in your `functions.php` file and want to use the widget manager in from the admin panel, you need to use [dynamic siderbars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) not `get_sidebar`. `get_sidebar` will only display the widgets that are coded into the file.

Instead of `<?php get_sidebar('404'); ?>` you should have something like `<?php dynamic_sidebar( '404' ); ?>`

Comment: So, while your answer didn't fix my issue, it did lead me to find the problem... which sheepishly I hate to admit was that I failed to reference the correct sidebar in my sidebar-404.php file. Yea... It was late. :) Thank you!